# Magento2.2.5 : How to maintain a session value in product detail page to custom controller page?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, session, magento-2.2.5, core-session

I implemented some custom options in the product pdp page. i.e, i have to engrave the product in frontend(eg.pendant FRONT SIDE) as well as the backend(eg.pendant BACK SIDE) without refreshing the page.. For making this i integrated the ajax call to engrave the front side of the product which is the custom module controller and once its completed i need to set the session variable for the back engraving option... that session value should be accessible in that product PDP page.

i set the some core session in **custom module controller page**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
              $coreSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface'); 
              $coreSession->start();
              $sidepart = array();
              $sidepart[0] = 'back';
              $setting =  $coreSession->setData('sidepart', $sidepart);
```

and get it by product pdp page

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $coreSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface'); 
  $coreSession->start();
  $getting_val =  $coreSession->getData('sidepart', array());
```

its not working even after setting the session..

PLEASE ADVICE ON THIS.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. I am trying to share the ideas based on my understand.

You mentioned without page refresh, you want to get the session value which is set by some custom controller in ajax call. Not sure how you will achieve this. You can access the session value either via page refresh / in some other page like cart / checkout. Otherwise you can store that value in your customer section data. which can be accessed at any point of time.

Comment: the session was set sucessfully but it will not reflect even the page is refresh too..but it will show the correct result while clearing the cache only 

sorry for my stupid communication